# how can make use response of multidimentional array in ajax that response in php but use in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is response of ajax

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Shoaib
            [description] => Shoaib is a frontend developer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => jawad
            [description] => jawad is a teacher
        )

)
```

above shown in `console.log()` how can handle in javascript

Comment: maybe use `echo json_encode($var)` instead of `var_dump($var)`, that would make it a lot easier to parse in JS.

Answer (score 0):

To use the response ( multi-dimensional array ) from your php script in javascript you would use `json_encode`

```
$arr=array();
$arr[]=array('name'=>'shaoaib');

$json=json_encode( $arr );
header('Content-Type: application/json' );
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

RamRaider has provided php end
so I will just focus on jquery part.

Your ajax part should be something like this

```
$.post(url, function(retObj){
     var data = JSON.parse(retObj);
     $.each(data, function(idx, val){
         console.log(val.name, val.description)
     })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function json_encode() this is just like a translator for the client about wha a answer is receiving from the server. The opossite is json_decode() to send information from client to server. 
Like this is how works:
I sent to the server a data object using ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    url : "ajax.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {"name" : "abipositas", "arr" : { "1" : "one", "2" : "two" } },
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(data["id_2"][2]);
                        alert(data["id_3"]);
                        alert(data["id_4"]);

                    },
                });
```

In the success of the ajax I just take the answer already interpreted from the server. And like this should be your server side:

```
<?php
if( $_POST ) {
    $arr['id_1'] = 'herbert';
    $arr['id_2'] = array( 0, 1, 7, 3 );
    $arr['id_3'] = $_POST['name'];
    $arr['id_4'] = $_POST['arr']['1'];

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Because I sent a object using `$_POST` I can ask if the `$_POST` information arrive correct. I don't care which specifically I ask for the package `($_POST)` in general. Is like if you received a package by your post and you are not at home, then you go to pick up in the next post office, you don't ask for the shoes in the package, you ask for your package. At home you open and use from the content what you need. Then you translate this message and send a answer back to the person that send you this package (the client using json_encode())